# Can't store object in user defaults

Tags: swift3

I have a class that conforms to `NSCoding`:

```
class Middleware : NSObject, NSCoding {

    var name: String
    var uri: String

    // MARK: NSCoding

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        uri = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "uri") as! String
    }

    func encode(with: NSCoder) {
        with.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        with.encode(uri, forKey: "uri")
    }
}
```

Storing that class in UserDefaults fails:

```
userDefaults.set(Middleware(name: "Volkszaehler Demo", uri: "http://demo.volkszaehler.org/middleware.php"), forKey: "middlewares")
```

Gives:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object  for key middlewares'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it- custom object needs to go through the encoder first:

```
let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: middleware)
```

encodedData can then be stored.

Comment: I get `[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`